# Removing sidebar for Catalog_Product_Edit based on role

Tags: layout, catalog, layout-update, user-roles, product-edit

We have a module that needs a customized product edit page based on the roles of "Administrator" and "Showcase". The showcase user doesn't need all of the stuff that the full admin has and my supervisor would like it so that they get just one page (w/o sidebar) and limited form options.

Is this possible? Are there tutorials? or even suggestions?

**UPDATE**
The image on the left is what I need the admin section to look like, the right, what I want the showcase user to look like.

[image]

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is something you can do (very general):

1. Create a module that will replace the original edit tabs
2. Figure out the role of the user
3. Add conditional logic.